# Neo4J connectivity and recommendation among a set of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, igraph, graph-databases

My database contains a set of nodes and one numeric type of relationship. Given set of nodes I would like to see whether and how they are connected to with each others as well as find nodes that can be included. I am sorry to not be able to synthesize a data. You can think of each node as a city and the relationship is a distance. If the relationship does not exist, means there is not direct way from city A to B. The idea has two fold 1) find whether and how these cities are connected. 2) find other intermediate cities.

For example, if I have A, B, C, D and E - one way is to do a pair-wise shortest distance. The graph is non-directional, so A-B is the same as B-A.

```
MATCH (n:people {name:'A'})-[r:INTERACTION]-(n2:people {name:'B'}),
      p = shortestPath ((n)-[*]-(n2))
RETURN p
```

However, instead of doing that `(n*n-1)/2` times, I can do something like this:

```
MATCH (n:people)-[r:INTERACTION]-(n2:people)
MATCH spath=shortestPath ((n)-[*]-(n2))
WHERE n.name in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] and n2.name in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
RETURN DISTINCT n.name, n2.name, r.score
```

Still, towards the second goal, finding other intermediate cities, I wonder if there is any other concept for doing such analysis within neo4j, and if not, how would you make sure, the output is distinct for each pair, meaning there is no A-B and B-A out, rather only one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly if you have a set of data and you want to do something with unique sets where the sets do not contain duplicates it would be best to produce that unique set of items first and then pass that to your query so you don't have to perform unecessary queries and then discard the redunt information afterwards.

To produce a uniqe set of pair sets you can do something like this.

```
// unwind the name collection twice to get all combinations
WITH ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] AS names
UNWIND names AS name1
UNWIND names AS name2

// makes sure the pairs are ordered and ignore identical pairs
WITH CASE 
       WHEN name1 = name2 THEN NULL 
       WHEN name2 < name1 THEN [name2, name1] 
       ELSE [name1, name2] 
     END AS pair

// collect all of the pairs
RETURN COLLECT (DISTINCT pair) AS pairs
```

If you are using APOC you could replace that with this

```
WITH ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] AS names
RETURN apoc.coll.combinations(names, 2) AS pairs
```

Putting it together with your query you can do something like this...

```
// from above
WITH ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] AS names
UNWIND names AS name1
UNWIND names AS name2
WITH CASE WHEN name1 = name2 THEN NULL WHEN name2 < name1 THEN [name2, name1] ELSE [name1, name2] END AS pair
WITH COLLECT (DISTINCT pair) AS pairs

// iterate over the unique pairs
UNWIND pairs AS pair

// find the shortest path 
// from  
// the first node identified by the first value in the pair
// to 
// the second node identified by the second value in the pair
MATCH spath = shortestPath((:people {name: pair[0]} )-[*..5]-(:people {name: pair[1]} ))

// produce a string representation of each path 
RETURN reduce(string = "", rel in relationships(spath) | string + startNode(rel).name + " " + type(rel) + " " + endNode(rel).name + ", ")
```

This query will return the minimum set of paths from your set of "destinations" without any duplication.

Comment: looks great - I think there is a "distinct" command needed on spath ? for some reason I see duplicate spath - but if I add distinct it looks better.

Comment: Any comments on the recommendation part ? the second goal ? Does it make sense to expect to have some sort of recommendations on other nodes, similar to the set ? ( I am new to neo4j so don't know what can expect !)

Comment: If the top returns a distinct set of pairs then you will get a distinct set of paths back. It may be that one path is contained in another path; think of a continguous line of cities. As for the seond goal, I am not sure I understand, the path will contain all of the intermediate cities.

Comment: You are right. Regarding the second goal, I think I need to make another question. As you answer here fulfill perfectly the question. If A is next to B and and A also next to C. if it happens B and C are connected to D (even though D is not connected to A). I would like to pull that out within neo4j wo posthoc analysis ! but again, this probably merits another separate question.

Comment: I added an APOC alternative to creating the combinations.

Comment: I use Cypher - probably if you add a line why one should consider using APOC help more people in the future.

Comment: I made the the other questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213115/neo4j-common-neighbors-of-a-set-nodes-in-a-path

Comment: nice - unforunately I am slammed this am and can't offer any comment. If it is still there at teh end of the day I will give it a go