# Neo4J common neighbors of a set nodes in a path

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

My network consists of nodes and the relationship is a numeric number. Think of it as a set of cities, and the relationship is the whether there is a road and if so how far is it.

I have path from my neo4j query, wonder how I can find the neighbor of this path given the following condition. These neighbors should be neighbor to more than one node in the path.
In the following picture, I have tried to illustrate what I mean. My path looks like the blue star below. I would like to find the green nodes. These green nodes, are connected to two or more nodes in the path. I have draw a few of these green nodes.

As an output I would like to have a path that include the blue path as well as the green ones.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

---

My original path looks like
[image]

If I use the suggested solution by @NonameCurious, I will have

[image]

As you can see the result is a group of nodes which there is no relationship. I assume it is because the query only returns nodes. However, I would like to have the connection between those "neighbors" with the original path be displayed on top of the original path.

Comment: The blue dots seem to belong to 2 disjoint paths (each of which has 3 blue dots).

Comment: you are right ! sorry, just updated the figure ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
WITH nodes(path) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
MATCH (a)--(node) WHERE NOT a IN nodes
WITH a, COUNT(DISTINCT node) AS relCounts
WITH a WHERE relCounts > 1
RETURN a
```

I am assuming `path` is given.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to filter relationships, you can use something like this:

```
WITH nodes(path) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
MATCH (a)-[r]-(node) WHERE NOT a IN nodes AND r.score > 27
WITH a, COUNT(DISTINCT node) AS relCounts
WITH a WHERE relCounts > 1
RETURN a
```

**SECOND UPDATE:**
If you just want to somehow get a subgraph of all the new nodes along with the old ones, you can do this

```
WITH nodes(path) AS nodes, path UNWIND nodes AS node MATCH (a)-[r]-(node) 
WHERE NOT a IN nodes AND r.score > 27 
WITH a, COLLECT(DISTINCT node) AS connectedNodes, COLLECT(DISTINCT r) AS connectedRels, path WHERE SIZE(connectedNodes) > 1 
UNWIND connectedNodes AS connectedNode 
UNWIND connectedRels AS connectedRel 
RETURN a, connectedRel, connectedNode, path
```

Comment: Thanks - how can I add a filter for relationship ? I used "(a)-[r]-(node)" but complains about r. I appreciate if you add the relationship filter as well.

Comment: What kind of filter do you need? What is your requirement?

Comment: I meant, filter on the relationship which is a numeric. So I would like the neithbors who are connected to more than two other nodes in the path with score larger than 27 for example :)

Comment: Thanks - Is there any way to add these nodes together with their relations to the path ? It seems, "a" here is just node - how about to have a new "path" that includes the original path and these nodes ?

Comment: It depends on how you want to create the new path. Note that a path is a sequence of nodes connected together through edges. Not every collection of nodes with some relationships between them is a path. So to answer your question, yes potentially you can do that but it depends on how you want to create the new path.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought as following: I already have a path - (the variable path in your query). Then I need to find those nodes that are connected to more than 2 nodes lets called them "A". Then I find the shortest path from each A to its contacts and then I make put all these paths together. (collapse/merge)

Comment: Nodes in "A" are directly connected to at least 2 nodes in "path" according to your definition. This means shortest path from those nodes to their contacts in "path" is  of size one, always. I am afraid I cannot follow what you wanna do. I suggest you post another question with a complete and clear problem definition because we are getting too far from the question in this thread.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion - you answer is right and and I am thankful. It is just the output - basically, I would like to visualize the output and science "A" is a set of node the visualization would be just a bunch of node - rather, I would like to visualize the whole thing (nodes and their connectivities). So we are still talking about the same question.

Comment: I can update the picture on how the visualization of the nodes from your answer looks like and make a mockup of what I wish to have ...

Comment: Yes that would help

Comment: I hope these figures explain it better. Thank you again.

Comment: If you just want to somehow get a subgraph of all the new nodes along with the old ones, you can do this.

==>
WITH nodes(path) AS nodes, path
UNWIND nodes AS node
MATCH (a)-[r]-(node) WHERE NOT a IN nodes AND r.score > 27
WITH a, COLLECT(DISTINCT node) AS connectedNodes, COLLECT(DISTINCT r) AS connectedRels, path WHERE SIZE(connectedNodes) > 1
UNWIND connectedNodes AS connectedNode
UNWIND connectedRels AS connectedRel
RETURN a, connectedRel, connectedNode, path
<==
But again I am not sure if there is particular requirement on how the new nodes should be returned along the path

Comment: That's what I needed, thanks. Please go ahead and update the answer :)